# How to replace standard Rich Text Edit with custom one?

Tags: rendering-template

I can't replace the standard Rich Text Edit with mine in the SharePoint 2013.

---

In the SharePoint 2010 and earlier I used aspx markup, like this:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="RichTextField" runat="server">
    <Template>
               ...
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

in a special ascx file in the folder (14 - for SharePoint 2010): c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\

---

In the SharePoint 2013 it doesn't work, moreover, if I change the standard markup of the:

```
 RenderingTemplate ID="RichTextField"
```

template, in the DefaultTemplates.ascx file, or even if I remove the DefaultTemplates.ascx file it changes nothing in the SharePoint2013!

---

Is there anybody who knows is it possible to replace the standard Rich Text Edit with a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 15 hive folder instead of 14 hive:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\template\controltemplates

Comment: Seems like he's aware of that from the question.